# CollectionView Issue with UIButton

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uibutton

I am using a `CollectionView` and `UIButton`. And I am facing some issue with my code. I want access `collectionViewCell` on Button Click. And the button is outside from the `collectionView`. 
So, How can I Access it?

```
if let cell = (sender as? UIButton)?.superview?.superview?.superview as? FavouriteVideosCell
    {
        let index = collectionview.indexPath(for: cell)
        let video_id = arrayFavouriteVideo[(index?.row)!].video_id
        RemoveVideoAPI(video_id: video_id)

    }
```

Comment: Share any screenshots reg this

Comment: @ktrkathir Actually my button is outside from collectionview and I want to access Video_ID from cell.

Comment: @ktrkathir approach is correct. You're not being cleared as outside of view hierarchy or not being yet dequeued or visible.

Comment: Can you please share usefull details

Comment: If it's the latter it can't be clicked. Else you can use cellForRow() method to access that cell using index.

Comment: Need screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
if let indexPath = collectionview.indexPath(for: cell) {

  let videoID = arrayFavouriteVideo[indexPath.item].video_id
  RemoveVideoAPI(video_id: videoID)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is completely wrong and not following any app architecture here.
But if you just want the videoID.

The simplest way to do that is to set the tag on button in your collectionView cellForItem method. And access it using tag property on your button without accessing cell.